# TypeScript: What is [c] in 'type Foo = { [c]: string; }'?

Tags: typescript

I was going through the [new features of TypeScript 2.9](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#typescript-29) and came across this part of code:

```
const c = "c";
const d = 10;
const e = Symbol();

const enum E1 { A, B, C }
const enum E2 { A = "A", B = "B", C = "C" }

type Foo = {
    a: string;       // String-like name
    5: string;       // Number-like name
    [c]: string;     // String-like name
    [d]: string;     // Number-like name
    [e]: string;     // Symbol-like name
    [E1.A]: string;  // Number-like name
    [E2.A]: string;  // String-like name
}

type K1 = keyof Foo;  // "a" | 5 | "c" | 10 | typeof e | E1.A | E2.A
```

What does `[c]: string;` inside `type Foo` mean and what is its purpose?

Comment: It's a JavaScript syntax; it's a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed property names allow you to use another variable to specify the name of a property.

Here is a shorter example:

```
const c = 'test';

const example = {
    [c]: 'test value'
};

// Note: this is for illustration - it works and shows what has happened
console.log(example.test);

// This is more likely how you would refer to the property
console.log(example[c]);
```

This particular example works as if `test` had been specified as the property name:

```
const example = {
    test: 'test value'
};

console.log(example.test);
```

You could use it, for example, to dynamically name a property on an object - referring to it by the variable that contains the name. TypeScript will track that variable in order to provide type information for the dynamic property, i.e. `example.[c] is a string`

Comment: I do understand now what it does, but I still don't really see the actual value of it. Guess I'll stumble on a use-case sooner or later =)